# find json data with php

Tags: php, json

I have some problem with php & json

first show my json file

```
{
  "api_json": [
    {
      "api_id": 1,
      "api_no": 36,
      "api_name": "name",
      "api_val": [
        133,
        424
      ]
    },
    {
      "api_id": 2,
      "api_no": 21,
      "api_name": "name2",
      "api_val": [
        213,
        924
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

and I wanna use `"api_name" = "name2"` to find `"api_no" = 21`

I tried read file and `$json['api_json'][0]['api_name']`

```
$file = "../api.json";
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true);
echo $json['api_json'][0]['api_name'];
```

but it can't find api_no by api_name

is there any suggest?

================================

Here is final

I success getting data though api_name but if I have up to 100 times to do this

my server can't handle it :(

So I use function and let json decode out of function

Finally it works!!

Thanks everybody's help!!

Here is my code

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("upload/server/ships.json"));
function shipdata($ship,$slot,$json){
    foreach($json->api_mst_ship as $ship_data) {
        if ($ship_data->api_name === $ship) {
            switch ($slot){
            case "id":
                return $ship_data->api_id;
                break;

            case "filename":
                foreach($json->api_mst_shipgraph as $ship_image) {
                    if ($ship_image->api_id === $ship_data->api_id) {
                        return $ship_image->api_filename;
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
};

echo shipdata('Bismarck','id');
echo shipdata('Bismarck','filename');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is likely to just loop over the results until you find the desired `api_name` value, and then output the `api_id` value in the current set. e.g.,

```
$data = json_decode($json);
foreach($data->api_json as $row) {
  if ($row->api_name === 'name2') {
        echo 'API Name "name2" found in api_id ', $row->api_id;
  }
}
```

Comment: It success but there is a new question, if my json file have up to 700 datas (include up to 50 element each), and I have to search up to 100+ times, in this solution, my server will too busy or not?

Comment: Sorry for many question, I will use function to do it and should I decode json every times or decode once when page loaded?

Comment: Decode it once and then loop over the results to build a new data structure that follows the pattern you want it in. For example: `$rows = []; foreach($data->api_json as $row) { $rows[$row->api_name] = $row; }`

Comment: Sorry I doesn't understand, I have many "api_json" like "api_json","api_json2","api_json3"

And each api_json should have different data stored in it.


Is it means I should read all json file and turn it to php array?

Answer (score 1):

I would use json decode then parse through it to get the correct value, it may require while or for loops

Here's a good source:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

I believe this may work but I haven't tested it

```
$json = json_decode($string);
echo $json->api_json[0]->api_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$result = $json['api_json'][1];
```

If you will access: `$result['api_no']`, it will give you 21

$result variable will have following values:

```
Array
(
    [api_id] => 2
    [api_no] => 21
    [api_name] => name2
    [api_val] => Array
        (
            [0] => 213
            [1] => 924
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put it into a function:

```
$json = json_decode($json, true);

$name = 'name';

function find_id_by_name($name, $api_array) {
    foreach($api_array['api_json'] as $key => $array) {
        if($array['api_name'] == $name) {
            return $array['api_no'];
        }
    }
}

echo find_id_by_name($name, $json);
```